# new list show up in RecyclerView after item deleted

Tags: list, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I got an issue when I tried to remove an item in a list. when I tried to remove a list it disappeared, but they show a new list. the case looks like this.

[image]

below I provided my code also

```
adapter.setOnItemClickedCallback(object : ListOrderAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {

        override fun onDecrementButtonClicked(orderMenu: OrderMenu, itemView: View, position: Int) {
            var quantityChanged = (orderMenu.quantity)!!.minus(1)

            itemView.tv_order_number.text = quantityChanged.toString()

            Log.e("Position", position.toString())
            if (quantityChanged > 0) {
                updateData(quantityChanged, orderMenu)

            } else {

                listItem.remove(orderMenu)
                recyclerView.removeViewAt(position)
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
                adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, listItem.size)

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Pesanan telah di hapus dari orderan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

        }

    })

}

private fun updateData(quantityChanged: Long, orderMenu: OrderMenu) {
    for (item in listItem){
        if (item.name.equals(orderMenu.name)){
            item.quantity = quantityChanged
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your image with mistake hasn't attached correct

Comment: I already put the correct image. thanks